# Get a list of dates from daterangepicker & show in listview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

i got Unexpected `null` value - if i put the `DateTime` manual it work but not showing the same range i picked??

**flutter**

```
import 'datesrange.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Dates Rang',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      /*routes: {
        "dateslist": (context) =>  DatesList(),
        "/": (context) => const HomeScreen(),
      },*/
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String done = "Done";
  DateTimeRange? _selectedDateRange;
  DateTime _startD = DateTime(2020);
  DateTime _endD = DateTime(2100);

  void _show() async {
    final DateTimeRange? result = await showDateRangePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: _startD,
      lastDate: _endD,
      currentDate: DateTime.now(),
      saveText: done,
    );

    if (result != null) {
      // Rebuild the UI
      print(result.start.toString());
      setState(() {
        _selectedDateRange = result;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime _startDate = DateTime.utc(2021, 03, 01);
    DateTime _endDate = DateTime.utc(2021, 02, 01);

    getDaysInBetween() {
      final int difference = _selectedDateRange!.start.difference(_selectedDateRange!.end).inDays;
      print(difference);
      return difference;
    }

    final items = List<DateTime>.generate(getDaysInBetween(), (i) {
      DateTime date = _selectedDateRange!.start;

      return date.add(Duration(days: i));
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('KindaCode.com'),
       actions: [IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.double_arrow_outlined),
          onPressed: () {
            getDaysInBetween();
          },
        ),],
      ),
      body: _selectedDateRange == null
          ? const Center(
              child: Text('Press the button to show the picker'),
            )
          : SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    // Start date
                    Text(
                      "Start date: ${_selectedDateRange!.start.toString().split(' ')[0]}",
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    // End date
                    Text(
                        "End date: ${_selectedDateRange!.end.toString().split(' ')[0]}",
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.red)),
                  Container(child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('Day ${items[index].day}'),
                      trailing: Text(
                          '${items[index].day}/${items[index].month}/${items[index].year}'),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            }),)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          ),
      // This button is used to show the date range picker
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _show();
          //Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dateslist');
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.date_range),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i got Unexpected null value - if i put the DateTime manual it work but not showing the same range i picked??

Answer (score 0):

Dont create variable inside build method, you can use `initState`  or use `late`

```dart
  DateTime _startDate = DateTime.utc(2021, 03, 01);
  DateTime _endDate = DateTime.utc(2021, 02, 01);

  getDaysInBetween() {
    final int difference =
        _selectedDateRange!.start.difference(_selectedDateRange!.end).inDays;
    print(difference);
    return difference;
  }

  late final items = List<DateTime>.generate(getDaysInBetween(), (i) {
    DateTime date = _selectedDateRange!.start;

    return date.add(Duration(days: i));
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

And void using `!`directly without checking null.

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String done = "Done";
  DateTimeRange? _selectedDateRange;
  DateTime _startD = DateTime(2020);
  DateTime _endD = DateTime(2100);

  void _show() async {
    final DateTimeRange? result = await showDateRangePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: _startD,
      lastDate: _endD,
      currentDate: DateTime.now(),
      saveText: done,
    );

    if (result != null) {
      // Rebuild the UI
      print(result.start.toString());
      setState(() {
        _selectedDateRange = result;
      });
    }
  }

  DateTime _startDate = DateTime.utc(2021, 03, 01);
  DateTime _endDate = DateTime.utc(2021, 02, 01);

  int getDaysInBetween() {
    if (_selectedDateRange == null) return 0;
    final int difference =
        _selectedDateRange!.end.difference(_selectedDateRange!.start).inDays;
    print(difference);
    return difference;
  }

  late final items = List<DateTime>.generate(getDaysInBetween(), (i) {
    DateTime date = _selectedDateRange?.start ?? DateTime.now();

    return date.add(Duration(days: i));
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('KindaCode.com'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.double_arrow_outlined),
            onPressed: () {
              getDaysInBetween();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _selectedDateRange == null
          ? const Center(
              child: Text('Press the button to show the picker'),
            )
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    // Start date
                    Text(
                      "Start date: ${_selectedDateRange?.start.day}",
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    // End date
                    Text("End date: ${_selectedDateRange?.end.day}",
                        style:
                            const TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.red)),
                    Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: items.length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                Card(
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    title: Text('Day ${items[index].day}'),
                                    trailing: Text(
                                        '${items[index].day}/${items[index].month}/${items[index].year}'),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            );
                          }),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
      // This button is used to show the date range picker
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _show();
          //Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dateslist');
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.date_range),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thx Yeasin its avoid the Unexpected null value, but i got two problems: 1- when i show the range in list & try to pick anther still show the same range picked befor. 2- if i choised dates between 1 to 30 it shows 29  or 1 to 5 it shows 4

Comment: not sure, try to rechecking the logic of date generation